# What exactly is an object? Where is the object here?

Tags: java, object

Sample code:

PrintMethod.java

```
public class PrintMethod {
    void print (String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

PrintS.java

```
class PrintS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintMethod pm = new PrintMethod(); //i know this is how you make a new object, but
        pm.print("Hello");
    }
}
```

Where is the object here? I've looked all over the internet, but what my teacher is telling me is different from what I found. Help?

And what then is the difference between an object and a class? If `PrintS` and `PrintMethod` are objects as well? I thought an object was an instance of a class? I'm so sorry, I just need this topic to be crystal clear.

Comment: can you please elaborate what your question is?

Comment: What have you found? What is your teacher opinion?

Comment: An object is an (any) instance of a class. There are several objects here, such as: the string array passed as an argument (and any strings that it contains), the `PrintMethod` instance created with the *new* operator, and the "Hello" string. `System.out` also evaluates to an object.

Comment: You explicitly have a comment that says that line is where the object is made.  What is the confusion?

Comment: There are at least eight objects involved here:  `args`, `"Hello"`, `pm`, the classes `PrintS`, `PrintMethod`, and `System`, and the stream `System.out`.

Comment: Well, my teacher once had a student point out the different parts (object, class and method) in the sample code he had given, and the student pointed to the variable String s in the method as an object and he said it was correct, and meanwhile on the internet I read something that "pm" in PrintMethod pm = new PrintMethod(); is the object. I'm still confused.

Comment: And what then is the difference between an object and a class? If PrintS and PrintMethod are objects as well? I thought object was an instance of a class? I'm so sorry, I just need this topic to be clear to my mind.

Comment: @user3026693, this seems like relatively beginner java. While Stack Overflow is a great resource for help with programming, it isn't really the best place to learn all the basics. I'd recommend and actual tutorial. This also seems to be basic [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) theory, which you should read about.

Comment: @Wold yes i know, my ideas are just very vague and confusing, because of the conflicting information I read. I'm sorry I asked that question on here, I just thought people would give better answers than the other places I've tried.

Comment: @user3026693, I really don't want to discourage you from using So, as it it is full of experienced and intelligent programmers who want to answer your questions. Just remember its a Q&A site, so questions like this are better answered by doing some research into the topic.

Comment: @Wold I'll keep that in mind next time. I had done a research, yes, patiently read every article I found, before I decided to go on here, because I thought I had no other options since I desperately needed a clear answer and the more I read more articles the more the answer gets confusing (not mentioning considering another conflicting answer from my instructor). And I actually found the clearest answer so far **here**.Thanks for the reminder though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Object` is the blueprint of a `Class` that gets created in Heap Memory. To get access to those objects we use `references` in Java Code.

So we don't directly access objects in Java Code. It is the `reference` that we access and use.

In your case `pm` is just an `reference` to a instance of `PrintMethod` placed in Heap memory. But `"Hello"` is a literal instance of a `String` that gets created in `String` pool.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best answer you can get can be found in the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html):

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a **new
>   object and returning a reference to that memory**. The new operator also
>   invokes the object constructor.
>
> Note: The phrase "instantiating a class" means the same thing as
>   "creating an object." **When you create an object, you are creating an
>   "instance" of a class**, therefore "instantiating" a class.
>   The new operator returns a reference to the object it created.

In your case, `pm` is a reference to an *object* of type `PrintMethod`. When you do `pm = new PrintMethod()` you are *constructing* a new *object*.

See the part of [Using Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html) in the official docs.

---

Clarification: When you say *class*, you usually refer to the code, it is simply a piece of code. But when you say *object*, you mean an *instance* of the class. Every *object* "belongs" to a class.

For example, consider a *class* named `Car`. All cars have wheels. An *instance* of `Car` would be a **specific car**, say `toyota`. So `toyota` is now an *instance* of `Car`.

Comment: so `print` is an/the object? because you said `pm` is a reference to _an_ object of type `PrintMethod`

Comment: @user3026693 No, `print` is a method that's defined in the class `PrintMethod`. See my edit, it might clarify things.

Comment: Thank you for this. I understand it better. I was already fine with my idea of what an object is until a classmate said that the `s` variable is _the_ object and my teacher accepted it as correct (he never mentioned that there were other objects in the sample code he had given except for the `s` variable). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> PrintMethod pm = new PrintMethod();

the left side part is called as Declaration and the right side part is called reference,where `new` which allocated the memory>

Answer (score 0):

We can define Object in 4 ways .

1) An Object is an Instance of a class ( Instance is nothing but allocating sufficient amount memory space for the data members and methods of a class )

2) Each and every class variable are also known as objects .

3) Blue print of a class is known as an object .

4) Each and every grouped Item is known as an object ( You know a grouped item is a variable which allows us to store multiple values of same type or different type or both at once )

So.,

Here i will give a small explanation about what is a object .

dear friend " Have you seen a Tree" ?????

Most of the people say that they have seen a tree . But Answer is Nooooo....

You never seen a tree but you have seen Types of tree like Banana Tree, Apple tree... etc

So here if you understand there is a very good beauty in it .

So a tree is a plan and Types of trees are Objects . So, Now tell me does a tree exists . Nooo its just a plan and based on that plan types of trees can be planted .

A class is a blue print and based on a class many objects can be created . So Always remember that "A class has Logical Existence " and "an Object has Physical Existence "

Answer (score 0):

**Objects** are building blocks of an OO program. A program that uses **OO** technology is basically a collection of objects.

Each **Object** is made up of the **Data & Behavior**.

Object Data: the Data stored within an  object represents the state of the **Object**. In OO programming terminology, this data is called **Attributes.**

Object Behavior: The behavior of an object is what the object can do. In OO programming terminology, these behaviors contained in methods,  and you invoke a method by sending a message to it.

Also i agree with the "Maroun Maroun."